# Solve for n in equation $y=nx^{n-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was attempting to rearrange the equation $y=nx^{n-1}$ for $n$. I tried looking for it for a while but could not find anything.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I removed the leading sentence since question posts should be focused on the question and directly relevant context. We even have an indicator for "new users" so it is not needed to mention this. I also removed several other comments, since they became obsolete with the answer given.

Comment: Try WolframAlpha. Probably something related to the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no elementary solution for this problem and unfortunately, the solution may also be non-algebra-precalculus.

You have
$y=nx^{n-1}$ or $ y\;  x \ln x=(n \ln x) e^{n\ln x}$

Now the Lambert W Function (see more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)) has the property that $b = a e^{a}$ is solved by $a = W(b)$. This
 allows solving the above equation, you get

$$
n \ln x = W(y\;  x \ln x)
$$

i.e.

$$
n  = \frac{W(y\;  x \ln x)}{\ln x}
$$